# Sorting content from different MySQL tables by date

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 different tables :

- News

  - news_id
  - news_content
  - news_pubdate
- Songs

  - song_id
  - song_link
  - song_pubdate
- Interview

  - interview_id
  - interview_artist
  - interview_content
  - interview_pubdate

I'm trying to create a timeline on my website to display all the content sorted by the pubdate from my 3 tables in a unique list. Is there a way to do that in MySQL ?

Maybe creating a 'general' table that would include all the ids sorted by date from my 3 other tables? I should then link all the element with PHP. Is it not too much power consuming ?

Comment: I believe all you would need would be a JOIN query. Can you give us an example record for each of the tables please so we can write you such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and see if it will meet your needs:

```
SELECT
    `news_id`      AS `id`,
    `news_content` AS `content`,
    `news_pubdate` AS `pubdate`,
    ""             AS `person`,
    "news"         AS `type`
FROM `news`

UNION
SELECT
    `song_id`      AS `id`,
    `song_link`    AS `content`,
    `song_pubdate` AS `pubdate`,
    ""             AS `person`,
    "song"         AS `type`
FROM `song`

UNION
SELECT
    `interview_id`      AS `id`,
    `interview_content` AS `content`,
    `interview_pubdate` AS `pubdate`,
    `interview_artist`  AS `person`,
    "interview"         AS `type`
FROM `interview`

ORDER BY `pubdate`;
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you so much!